# Trying to find an efficient way to use a while loop in pandas that references the previous row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to run this custom function over thousands of rows of data multiple times quickly.  The way I think to solve this takes a long time to run.

I have tried to use .apply but I cannot see how to only apply over certain rows. I have thought about trying to store the previous row solution as a variable, but cannot reason the code out and think it might be the same speed.

The below code is a sample of what I'm trying to make more efficient.  This is like the excel version here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dt0KQg52c6c&t=274s
at 4 mins 30 seconds

I'm new to coding and self taught, if anyone can point me in a direction that can help me think of a way to compute this in a non-loop variety, it would be greatly helpful to me and applicable to my future understanding of coding, thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

start_program = time.time()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-09-01','2019-09-02','2019-09-03','2019-09-04','2019-09-05','2019-09-06'], 'price':[10,8,5,20,50,60]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

df.insert(1,'AVG', "")

df['AVG'] = df['AVG'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

df.iloc[3, df.columns.get_loc('AVG')] = np.mean(df['price'].iloc[0:4])

def avgfunc(df,target_column,price_column,row,num_avg):
    df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc(target_column)] = ((df[target_column].iloc[row -1]*(num_avg - 1))+df[price_column].iloc[row])/num_avg
    return df.iloc[row, df.columns.get_loc(target_column)]

leng = len(df['price'])

i=4
while i < leng:
    avgfunc(df,'AVG','price',i,5)
    i += 1      

print(df)

end_program = time.time()
print("Total time to complete program is :", end_program - start_program)

$ python test_loop.py
        price  AVG
Date
2019-09-01     10    NaN
2019-09-02      8    NaN
2019-09-03      5    NaN
2019-09-04     20  10.75
2019-09-05     50  18.60
2019-09-06     60  26.88
Total time to complete program is : 0.03003978729248047
```

Comment: Instead of posting a (rather) long piece of code, you should probably explain what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `numpy`

```
ave= np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: (a+b)/2,2,1)
v=ave.accumulate(df.price.values, dtype=np.object)
v
Out[525]: array([1, 1.5, 2.25, 3.125, 4.0625, 5.03125], dtype=object)
```

Or we can speed up with `numba`

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def ave(x):
    total = 1
    result = []
    for y in x:
        total = (y+total)/2
        result.append(total)
    return result
ave(df.price.values)
Out[528]: [1.0, 1.5, 2.25, 3.125, 4.0625, 5.03125]
```

Comment: This is a pretty clever answer.

Comment: wow, thanks for the fast reply. It took me some time to understand what you did. but I guess I should have been clearer. I need that NAN to be there. I would like to adapt this to different ranges of averages. For example, if I averaged the first 4 rows instead, then I need the code to multiply that average by 4 then add in the 5th price and divide the result by 5. that then needs to progress down the column. I will edit my sample code. I kept the average down to keep the amount of data down. Can you help me adapt this?

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `accumulate` from itertools:

```
from itertools import accumulate
np.fromiter(accumulate(df.price,lambda x,y: (x+y)/2),float)
 array([1.     , 1.5    , 2.25   , 3.125  , 4.0625 , 5.03125])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for row N you are trying to calculate the mean of the column labeled `"price"` over a window of itself and the previous N-1 rows in the DataFrame, starting at N=4, right?  You are just doing so in an iterative way, row by row, requiring the result of the previous row to inform the next row.

Clever, but pandas performs quite poorly when iterating over rows of DataFrames, so this should be avoided at all cost.  Have you considered an expanding window calculation using [`Series.expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html#pandas.Series.expanding)?

```
df["AVG"] = df["price"].expanding(min_periods=4).mean()
```

The argument `min_periods` specifies the width of the initial window.  This will skip the first 3 rows in the `"price"` column, setting the values of those rows in `"AVG"` to `NaN`.  It will then calculate the mean of the first 4 rows in `"price"` and use that for the 4th element of `"AVG"`, the mean of the first 5 rows of `"price"` and use that for the 5th element of `"AVG"`, and so on.